# How to create a train_test_split based on a conditional in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I know how to utilize a basic `train_test_split`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)
```

However, what if I want to divide my training and testing set by a variable, in this case `year`. I want all values where `year==2019` to be my test set while `year<2019` is my training set. How can I alter the code above to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain with an example:
If your corpus have 1000 data points and you want 700/300 for train/test, find data points with `year == 2019` take (move) them to the end of the corpus and consider them as test data with something like bellow: (suppose 200 data point satisfy `year == 2019` condition)

```
X_test, y_test = X[800:1000], y[800:1000]
```

and for example 300 data points have `year < 2019` after moving them to top:

```
X_train, y_train = X[0:300], y[0:300]
```

Now for rest of your corpus (from 300 to 800) redefine X and Y like:

```
X = data.iloc[301:799]
Y = label.iloc[301:799]
```

and then use `train_test_split` for new X and Y and join new  `X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train` with the previous ones.