# Train_Test_Split based on specific column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, train-test-split

My question is rather close to [How to create a train_test_split based on a conditional in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758244/how-to-create-a-train-test-split-based-on-a-conditional-in-python)

but I am looking for a better solution.

I have a pandas dataframe where I would typically use the `train_test_split` function

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data[xvars], data[yvar], train_size=0.98, random_state=42)
```

However, I would like to split based on my pandas column called `week` where week < 51 would be train set, and week >= 51 would be test set, how can I achieve this efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I sorted the dataframe, and then I apply the solution stated in the doc with shuffle and stratify both set to False.

The solution to this problem is stated in the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, shuffle=False, test_size=0.4, stratify=None)
```